# Linker error in c++ program on Windows 7

Tags: c++

I just wanted to try the compiler option but getting the linker error. g++ used is 4.7.2 on windows 7 through MinGW

The code is a simple test code named test.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#define max 10

int main()
{
 int a;
 int arr[max];
 cout<<"this is the sample text"<<endl;
 system("pause");
}
```

Now i started compiling step by step :

```
1.cpp test.cpp>test.i
2.g++ -S test.i
3.as -o test.o test.s
4.ld -o test.exe test.o
```

First three steps are fine,in the last step i'm getting following error :

```
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `__main'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `std::cout'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `system'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `atexit'
ld: test.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
```

Comment: Did you try linking the last step with -lstdc++ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not passing the required libraries (the standard C++ library, by example) and other object files to `ld`.

I do not work on windows, but I think that simply to do:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

should work. `g++` automatically does the preprocessing and linking for you.

Comment: @irleon: the standard command "g++ -o test.exe test.cpp" is working fine it's only if i break the automatic compilation procedure as mentioned above in 4 steps  then only i'm getting issue at last step

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your object file agains `libstdc++`, `libc`, and also a C runtime since you're building an executable. `ld` doesn't do this by default.

Here is the minimal viable set of arguments required to link your example on my system (Ubuntu 15.04/g++ 4.9.2, but on your system it will look pretty similar):

```
 ld     \
 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2    \
 -o test.exe     \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o     \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o     \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o   \
 test.o \
 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9    \
 -lstdc++ -lc   \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o     \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

As you can see, it's pretty long. This is one of the reasons you rarely want to use `ld` directly.

Also, notice that the sequence of commands you're issuing is not the same to what `g++` does under the hood when you issue a command like `g++ -o test.exe test.cpp`. To see what it actually does, try passing `g++` the `--verbose` (or simply `-v`) argument: `g++ -o test.exe test.cpp --verbose`.